# Kmplayer 64x doesn't display smart subtitles like .ssa/.ass with all the effects properly

Tags: video, kmplayer

When playing videos that contain smart subs like .ssa/.ass the newest kmplayer 64x version doesn't display it properly. it shows it as a generic .srt subtitle and not with all of the effects of smart subs.

I tried to mess around in the configuration in subtitle tab but to no use. It still doesn't work well.

The previous versions of Kmplayer can play those videos with smart subs fine but the newest version doesn't.

Can anyone please help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of windows are you using?
This method works for me everytime:
Just create a new user account or a turn guest account from control panel and try to play the video again see if it works .
Works for me everytime
Btw does your system meets the requirements of the software/video player

Answer (score 0):

Press f2
Subtitle processing -> multi-sub/etc -> Advanced
Now you just make sure "force user's font settings" option is off